# auto-complete class and id name in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext

In Dreamweaver, I can autocomplete the class name or id name of a style sheet in CSS all the time. In Sublime Text 3, I can't. Why not? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the true way 
at first you should install the package install 
after that you should search for all auto complete and install it . you will now see hoe it work .really it is amazing tool .